# Visual Studio "FileNotFoundException : Could not load assembly" issue, but without file name?

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, cross-platform, filenotfoundexception

[image: screenshot]

I am trying to work on a cross-platform mobile app using xamarin with visual studio 2015. However, after downloading what I think was all of android sdk/tool, I am getting the exception from the screenshot.

I read multiple if not most of "cannot load assembly" problems from Googling, but most of them have associated file url/name while I have got none of that.

Really desperate to know if anyone had come across this since this is my first time using visual studio & C#, and I am overwhelmed by the amount of new things I am learning.

Thanks

Aloe

Comment: What version of Xamarin are you using? I'd first make sure that you have the latest version, since I've seen this kind of problems a few months ago but not lately.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Tbh, I do not know which version I downloaded... But it came with the latest download of visual studio 2015 from the website. 

What's really weird is that, if I don't create a cross-platform template, but a blank android template, the error is non-existent.

Comment: This looks like something to do with Profile you are using on xamarin as error says or make sure that you have installed correct android api version.

Comment: I have installed android sdk api 24 and 19. I wanted to begin with the nost recent but the project breaks without api 19. So i got those two.

Comment: EDIT: making answer instead in case it does fix the issue. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API 24 is not fully supported in the current stable Xamarin release. It is only fully supported on a web Preview. See: 
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/introduction-to-android-n/ .

So use API 23 instead and I would uninstall API 24.

Also do not use the android sdk build tools version 24 as that has been having issues as well. See: 
https://releases.xamarin.com/technical-bulletin-android-sdk-build-tools-24/